# How to stream a USB webcam connected to a raspberry pi using gstreamer (RTMP)

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, webcam, rtmp

I am really hitting a wall when trying to use gstreamer to stream my usb webcam to a RTMP server. The command I keep using is this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e /dev/video0 is-live=true ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://<server>'
```

The problem is, it keeps failing with this error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no source element for URI "/dev/video0"
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. This command is not set in stone I need to be able to just stream my usb webcam to an RTMP server in the end. It is a raspberry pi 4 with the latest 64bit OS.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the first plugin, v4l2src:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://<server>'
```

Comment: When I run this command, I get `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no property "is-live" in element "v4l2src0"`.

Comment: You're correct, this is a property from videotestsrc, not from v4l2src (which is always live). I'll edit my answer for removing that bad advice.